# HTML DOM Elements Global Scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When helping someone, I had an interesting situation. They wondered why the code below worked:

```
<input type="text" id="myElem" value="Nice" />

$(function() {
    var myElem = $("myElem");
    myProblem();
});

var myProblem = function() {
    var result = myElem.value; //This Works
    result = myElem.val(); //Doesn't Work
}
```

At first I didn't have a good answer, because my current thinking is both statements in the myProblem method should fail, but only one failed. Later I learned browsers scope all HTML elements globally.

So explaining how this problem is solved is by myElem will be in scope as a JQuery object within the on load function, however the JQuery object will become out-of-scope when it is inside myProblem method and, because browsers scope all HTML elements globally, myElem will be scoped as a HtmlInputElement.

I have been writing code for awhile, and for me to just learn browsers are scoping all HTML elements globally was news to me.

I understand the code sample and why it works. My question is how early have browsers been doing this? Is this a latest trend or have I missed something? Do all browsers support this?

After some research, I found the latest browsers support, but how about IE6+, etc.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"I understand the code sample and why it works. My question is how early have browsers been doing this? Is this a latest trend or have I missed something? Do all browsers support this?"*

This was originally an IE feature that was non-standard. If I recall, Opera may have been first to adopt it, followed by Chrome when it came around.

More recently, Firefox has adopted it. As such, love it or hate it, the majority of modern browsers implement this feature, but if you're supporting legacy browsers, you'll find some (especially Firefox) that do not have it.

Many recommend to not rely on this feature. Ultimately up to you and what browsers your project must support.

Comment: Thank you, you mention "this was originally and IE feature" what version is early - IE6? I wonder if there is any compatibility chart which browsers support.

Comment: It exists in IE6, and probably earlier, but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

it is because inside `myProblem` you are accessing a global variable called `myElem` which is exposed to the global scope by the browser... it is the dom element with name/id `myElem` so it does not have jQuery wrapper method like `.val()` associated with it

The spec can be [found here](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#named-access-on-the-window-object)

```
$(function() {
    //this creates a local scope variable holding jQuery wrapper object, which is accessable only inside the scope of this function
    var myElem = $("myElem");
    myProblem();
});

var myProblem = function() {
    //here myElem refers to the dom element with id/name myElem which is exposed to the global scope
    var result = myElem.value; //This Works
    result = myElem.val(); //Doesn't Work
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying to find out what browsers support scoping HTML elements globally. I just recently learned browsers supporting scoping all HTML elements globally. Wondering if there is a compatibility chart.