# Does jQuery create a globally scoped object for each element with an id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've noticed that, in Firefox at least, jQuery seems to create a global variable for each element on the page that has an id, and calls that variable whatever the id is.  In this image from Firebug, see how I've got an element called `querystring`, but I also seem to have a global variable also called `querystring`:

[image]

The type of this variable `HtmlInputElement`, because the element is defined as:

```
<input id="querystring" ...>
```

Is this a global shortcut in jQuery, such that `varname` is the same as `$('#varname')`, or am I not understanding what I'm seeing here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML DOM Elements Global Scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20753992/html-dom-elements-global-scope)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually an HTML5 thing, not just jQuery.

This code shows a nice example of it:

```
<a id="yestheyreglobals">Are IDs globals?</a>

<script>
    if ( yestheyreglobals ) {
        document.write('Yes they\'re globals')
    }
</script>
```

Paste it in an empty .html file and watch the magic. No jQuery required.

source: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Arasd

Even though this works, it isn't supported in all browsers, so one should still rely on `document.getElementById`.

Also a link to the WHATWG standard in case anyone is curious:  http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#named-access-on-the-window-object